# Should I disable systemd-resolve for a docker-hosted DNS solution?

Tags: docker, dns, port, coredns

I've been wanting to run my own local DNS server in Docker and open up the standard port 53 for DNS queries. However, I saw that `systemd-resolve` is using port 53 on my Ubuntu host (where the Docker engine runs on). I'd rather not use a different port for my new DNS container. My questions:

- What does `systemd-resolve` do?
- Can I disable `systemd-resolve`?
- SHOULD I disable `systemd-resolve` in favour of a self-hosted DNS server?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: The first point should get its answer with https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-resolved.html#. Note that it listens only on `127.0.0.53` not on all IP addresses. It is only a recursive service, if you need to have an authoritative nameserver on the box, both can cohabit as doing different things.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I indeed overlooked that `systemd-resolve` only listens on `127.0.0.53:53`. For me it's sufficient to let the external DNS listen on a specific interface.